# Using present progressive to describe something

Tags: present-continuous

I found this line on Facebook. I wonder if this construction is allowed grammatically.

> Does it matter to be consistent with the language in which **we are
> speaking**?....

Why didn't they write **in which we speak** since we're not speaking at that time?

Comment: Certainly it is allowed. If you are referring to the way you use a language, the reference is to a time when you _are_ speaking.

Comment: Should it be so unusual for someone to type "what are you talking about?" or "what are you trying to say?" in online chat.  Yet, they are not talking. They are not saying anything.  Only typing on a keyboard.  Likewise with your quote.  The real question is whether it's completely grammatical to say "Does it matter to be consistent" instead of "Does being consistent matter?"